# Excel Macros VBA run at nth minutes

Tags: excel, vba

How can i run the macros at every Nth minute of the hour like 1:40 , 2:40 , 3:40 ... so on.
Even I run it at 1:35 , it should execute only at mentioned Nth minute like 1:40 .
Can anyone help me with this?.

Comment: Look at `Application.OnTime`

Answer (score 1):

Your might use the function below to return the time to assign to the Timer.

```
Function NextTime(ByVal StartAt As Integer, _
                  ByVal Interval As Integer) As Double
    ' StartAt is the minute of an hour
    
    Dim Fun         As Double
    Dim m           As Integer
    
    Fun = Now()
    StartAt = StartAt Mod Interval
    m = Right(Format(Fun, "hh:mm"), 2)        ' current minute
    For m = m To (m + Interval)
        If m Mod (StartAt + Interval) = 0 Then Exit For
        Fun = Fun + (1 / 24 / 60)
    Next m
    NextTime = Fun
End Function
```

The function call requires 2 arguments, both of them given in minutes, meaning they are both <=60. `Interval` is the number of minutes between calls. `StartAt` is the minute at which you want to start off counting intervals. So, with a StartAt = 0 and Interval = 20 `NextTime` will return a time of 20 past, 40 past or on the hour, depending upon the current time. If StartAt = 6 the function would return 6 past, 26 past and 46 past while the interval remains 20.

`NextTime(40, 60)` would return a time 40 minutes past the hour every hour. Use this sub for trial and testing.

```
Private Sub Try()
    Debug.Print Format(NextTime(6, 20), "dd/mm/yy hh:mm")
End Sub
```

Comment: how can i run another Sub using this function?

like 

Sub test1()
MsgBox ("Hi")
End Sub 

Sub test2()
Call test1
End Sub

Comment: I don't understand. The Sub `Try` above ***is*** another sub that is calling the function. Instead of  `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:20:00"), "Macro1"` you might use `Application.OnTime NextTime("6, 20), "Macro1"`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Macro named 'Macro1'...Insert in 1st line of code in Macro1

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:40:00"), "Macro1" ' runs every 40 minutes...
```

Then, in the Thisworkbook module add the following macro.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Macro1
End Sub
```

This process will take over your system, I think, and you'll have problems running other processes, which will compete with this process, especially when running Excel apps, unless you always launch Excel as a new instance from your other Excel instance (the one that is constantly running or waiting to run).

Comment: I have tried with this , actually I have faced two problems
1. It will count the interval from start of the minute like if i run it at 1am ,i will run at 1:40 , 2:20 like that